# How to show category subcategory based on array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array that consists of some data to show the category and subcategories.

```
{id: "5", parent_id: "0", lable: "Movie"}
{id: "20", parent_id: "5", lable: "Action"}
{id: "15", parent_id: "43", lable: "J.K Rowling"}
{id: "43", parent_id: "0", lable: "Book"}
{id: "20", parent_id: "2", lable: "James Bond Series"}
{id: "3", parent_id: "0", lable: "Music"}
{id: "39", parent_id: "15", lable: "Harry Potter Series"}
```

I want to sort and show this data something like this :

```
> Movie
>> Action  
>>>James Bond Series

>Book
>>J.K Rowling
>>>Harry Potter Series
```

Comment: What have you tried? adding your efforts can help us to understand better the problem to made a solution for you.

Comment: For the object where "lable" is James Bond Series, did you mean for the parent_id to be 20?

Comment: looks like, you need a tree for getting a sorted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the tree representation of your data since your data is a self-reference table. So, you need to write a code that will translate your flat structure to a tree. For example, you can use the following code to do this:

```
const makeTree = (array, id, parentId, parentValue) =>
  array
    .filter(node => {
      return node[parentId] === parentValue;
    })
    .map(node => {
      node["items"] = makeTree(array, id, parentId, node[id]);
      return node;
    });
```

Where `array` is your source array, `id` - the name of the ID field, `parentId` - the name of the field that holds the parent ID, `parentValue` - the root node ID.

You can call this function as the follows to make a tree from your array:

```
const tree = makeTree(array, "id", "parent_id", "0");
```

Where `array` is your source array:

```
const array = [
  { id: "5", parent_id: "0", lable: "Movie" },
  { id: "20", parent_id: "5", lable: "Action" },
  { id: "15", parent_id: "43", lable: "J.K Rowling" },
  { id: "43", parent_id: "0", lable: "Book" },
  { id: "2", parent_id: "20", lable: "James Bond Series" },
  { id: "3", parent_id: "0", lable: "Music" },
  { id: "39", parent_id: "15", lable: "Harry Potter Series" }
];
```

The resultant array elements will contain the `items` field that is an array of child nodes.

After this, you can create a recursive function that will render this tree using jQuery. For example:

```
const renderLevel = items => {
  return $("<ul>").append(
    items.map(item =>
      $("<li>")
        .html(item.lable)
        .append(renderLevel(item.items))
    )
  );
};
```

Call it and pass the `tree` variable to it:

```
$(() => {
  $("body").append(renderLevel(tree));
});
```

This is a [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRyRxX?editors=1010).

```js
const array = [
  { id: "5", parent_id: "0", lable: "Movie" },
  { id: "20", parent_id: "5", lable: "Action" },
  { id: "15", parent_id: "43", lable: "J.K Rowling" },
  { id: "43", parent_id: "0", lable: "Book" },
  { id: "2", parent_id: "20", lable: "James Bond Series" },
  { id: "3", parent_id: "0", lable: "Music" },
  { id: "39", parent_id: "15", lable: "Harry Potter Series" }
];

const makeTree = (array, id, parentId, parentValue) =>
  array
    .filter(node => {
      return node[parentId] === parentValue;
    })
    .map(node => {
      node["items"] = makeTree(array, id, parentId, node[id]);
      return node;
    });

const tree = makeTree(array, "id", "parent_id", "0");
console.log(JSON.stringify(tree))

const renderLevel = items => {
  return $("<ul>").append(
    items.map(item =>
      $("<li>")
        .html(item.lable)
        .append(renderLevel(item.items))
    )
  );
};

$(() => {
  $("body").append(renderLevel(tree));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a general solution, you can take your data and implement a light tree class where each node has a value and a list of children of the node. Then you can create an iterator or similar function that will do a depth-first traversal of the tree. It can return the depth information which will allow you print the values with the proper indentation.

```js
let data = [{id: "5", parent_id: "0", lable: "Movie"},{id: "20", parent_id: "5", lable: "Action"},{id: "15", parent_id: "43", lable: "J.K Rowling"},{id: "43", parent_id: "0", lable: "Book"},{id: "2", parent_id: "20", lable: "James Bond Series"},{id: "3", parent_id: "0", lable: "Music"},{id: "39", parent_id: "15", lable: "Harry Potter Series"}]


class Node {
  constructor(id, value) {
      this.id = id
      this.value = value
      this.children = []
    }
    * getTree(depth = 0) {  // an iterator that yields itself and chidlren
      yield [this.value, depth]
      for (let child of this.children) {
        yield* child.getTree(depth + 1)
      }
    }
}

// Create the nodes using a helper object to keep track of IDs
// Make sure the parent exists (even without info) before trying to push children

let tree = data.reduce((tree, {id,parent_id, lable}) => {
  if (tree[id] === undefined) tree[id] = new Node(id, lable)
  else Object.assign(tree[id], {id,value: lable})

  if (tree[parent_id] == undefined) tree[parent_id] = new Node()

  tree[parent_id].children.push(tree[id])
  return tree
}, { 0: new Node(0, "root")})

// Root of the tree is at id 0
let root = tree[0]

// now iterate of the children using the depth for layout
for (let [node, depth] of root.getTree()) {
  console.log('>'.repeat(depth), node)
}

// Show only movies by starting at a different node:
console.log("----------- movies -------------")
let start = tree[5]
for (let [node, depth] of start.getTree()) {
  console.log('>'.repeat(depth), node)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with a recursive method.

```js
const arr = [{id: "5", parent_id: "0", lable: "Movie"},
{id: "20", parent_id: "5", lable: "Action"},
{id: "15", parent_id: "43", lable: "J.K Rowling"},
{id: "43", parent_id: "0", lable: "Book"},
{id: "20", parent_id: "2", lable: "James Bond Series"},
{id: "3", parent_id: "0", lable: "Music"},
{id: "39", parent_id: "15", lable: "Harry Potter Series"}];

const render = (arr, id) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = arr.find(e => e.id === id).lable;
  div.appendChild(span);
  arr.filter(e => e.parent_id === id).forEach(sub => {
    div.appendChild(render(arr, sub.id));
  });
  return div;
}

arr.filter(e => e.parent_id === "0").forEach(main =>    document.querySelector('div').appendChild(render(arr, main.id)));
```

```css
div {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use filter function like below for every category and subcategory:

```js
var arr = [{id: "5", parent_id: "0", lable: "Movie"},
{id: "20", parent_id: "5", lable: "Action"},
{id: "15", parent_id: "43", lable: "J.K Rowling"},
{id: "43", parent_id: "0", lable: "Book"},
{id: "20", parent_id: "2", lable: "James Bond Series"},
{id: "3", parent_id: "0", lable: "Music"},
{id: "39", parent_id: "15", lable: "Harry Potter Series"}];

function isParent(element, index, array) {
  return (element.parent_id == "0");
}

let filtered = arr.filter(isParent);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get first a tree and then a flat representation.

```js
function getTree(array, root) {
    var o = {};
    array.forEach(payload => {
        Object.assign(o[payload.id] = o[payload.id] || {}, { payload });
        o[payload.parent_id] = o[payload.parent_id] || {};
        o[payload.parent_id].children = o[payload.parent_id].children || [];
        o[payload.parent_id].children.push(o[payload.id]);
    });
    return o[root].children;
}

function getFlat(array = []) {
    return array.reduce((r, { payload, children }) =>
        r.concat(payload, getFlat(children)), []);
}

var data = [{ id: "5", parent_id: "0", lable: "Movie" }, { id: "20", parent_id: "5", lable: "Action" }, { id: "15", parent_id: "43", lable: "J.K Rowling" }, { id: "43", parent_id: "0", lable: "Book" }, { id: "2", parent_id: "20", lable: "James Bond Series" }, { id: "3", parent_id: "0", lable: "Music" }, { id: "39", parent_id: "15", lable: "Harry Potter Series" }],
    result = getFlat(getTree(data, '0'));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```